# Sidecar connection problem

Tags: ipad, imac, catalina, ipados, sidecar

I have a 6th gen iPad (v13.1.3) and an iMac 27 2019 (latest 10.15) on the same wifi network. I can choose my iPad from the dropdown of the sidecar menu, but I always get "Unable to Connect to “iPad name” error message while connecting. I tried it with both wifi and cable without any success. Previously about a week (and few versions) ago I was able to connect. I can see any options to set or debug the connection.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Is the error just 'unable to connect to 'iPad name'' or is there more?

Comment: It also shows: "The device timed out."